# How to extract a string from tuple index based on if-else condition in pandas?

Tags: pandas, numpy, if-statement, tuples, python-itertools

My dataframe `df.shape (105,6)`

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import ast

     """  Ccom  Wcom  Lcom  Dcom  Total    Winner
(A1, A2)  -1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0    1.0    (A1, A2) 
(A1, A3)  -1.0  -1.0   1.0   1.0    0.0    (A1, A3)
(A1, A4)   1.0  -1.0   1.0   1.0    2.0    (A1, A4)
(A1, A5)  -1.0  -1.0  -1.0   1.0   -2.0    (A1, A5)
(A1, A6)  -1.0  -1.0   0.0   1.0   -1.0    (A1, A6) """
```

I want the name of index (viz tuple) in Winner column of dataframe based on the condition

```
if(df.Total > 0) --> Winner left i.e Winner = A1
elif(df.Total < 0) --> Winner right one i.e Winner = A2
elif(df.Total == 0 ) --> Winner='Draw' And keep a count of draw in both A1 and A2
```

Output should be something like:

```
           Ccom  Wcom  Lcom  Dcom  Total    Winner
(A1, A2)  -1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0    1.0       A1 
(A1, A3)  -1.0  -1.0   1.0   1.0    0.0      Draw
(A1, A4)   1.0  -1.0   1.0   1.0    2.0       A1
(A1, A5)  -1.0  -1.0  -1.0   1.0   -2.0       A5
(A1, A6)  -1.0  -1.0   0.0   1.0   -1.0       A6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with select values in tuples in index by indexing `[0]`, `[1]`:

```
m1 = df.Total > 0
m2 = df.Total < 0

df['Winner'] = np.select([m1, m2], [df.index.str[0], df.index.str[1]], default='Draw')
print (df)
         Ccom  Wcom  Lcom  Dcom  Total Winner
(A1,A2)  -1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0    1.0     A1
(A1,A3)  -1.0  -1.0   1.0   1.0    0.0   Draw
(A1,A4)   1.0  -1.0   1.0   1.0    2.0     A1
(A1,A5)  -1.0  -1.0  -1.0   1.0   -2.0     A5
(A1,A6)  -1.0  -1.0   0.0   1.0   -1.0     A6
```

Comment: This works, but what if I want to directly pick the string from the index without pre defining the Winner Column with (str[0], str[1]) ? Is there a way?

Comment: @Zee - sure, use `df.index.str[0]` and `df.index.str[1]`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. And keeping count of number of draws for `df.index.str[0]` and `df.index.str[1]` if it's a draw? `df.value_count()` It's not wokring. Coz I'm using `df.Winner.value_counts()` for win counts. I'm getting counts of draws. I want count of `index.str` count for draws

Comment: @Zee - Do you think `df.Winner.eq('Draw').sum()` what is same like `df.Total.eq(0).sum()` ?

Comment: Yes they're equal. But I want number of time A1 has draws, A2 has draws and so on... Not total count of draws in df

Comment: sorry, typo. `df[df.Total.eq(0)].index.str[0].value_counts()`

Comment: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'value_count'

Comment: @Zee - What is your pandas version? It should working - [`Index.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.value_counts.html)

Comment: @Zee - oops, missing last `s` - `value_counts`